# WPF VirtualizingStackPanel not redrawing on horizontal resize

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an `ItemsControl` with a vertical `VirtualizingStackPanel` that has items with wrapping `TextBlocks`. Horizontally resizing the parent container fails to re-draw the elements below a certain size, only redrawing once you've scrolled up/down. However above a certain size the redrawing happens correctly. This only seems to be an issue when Virtualization is enabled.

I've created a simple example which demonstrates the issue here...

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfTesting.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTesting"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindow}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LongStrings}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Margin="5" 
                        Padding="5"
                        Background="Gray"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        CornerRadius="8">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Text="{Binding}"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True"
                              Focusable="False">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

CodeBehind...

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<string> LongStrings { get; }
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        LongStrings = Enumerable.Range(1, 20)
            .Select(_ => new string(Enumerable.Repeat('a', 1000).ToArray()))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a little silly that the solution is so simple but you can fix it relatively easily by binding the `Width` property of the Item you're displaying to the `ActualWidth` property of the `VirtualizingStackPanel`.

```xml
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=StackPanel}">
            <Border Margin="5"
                    Padding="5"
                    Background="Gray"
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    CornerRadius="8">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Text="{Binding}"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel x:Name="StackPanel"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Frankly I'm convinced that the rendering behaviour of the `VirtualizingStackPanel` is a bug given just how odd it is.

Comment: It looks like a bug indeed. Really strange is the fact that the TextBlock wrapping apparently always uses the correct available width.